# Is stationary state possible to be achieved for some arbitrary heat radiating objects in an adiabatic room while they have different temperatures?

Tags: thermodynamics, thermal-radiation, equilibrium

Assume an adiabatic room and some objects in it. Heat is only able to exchange via radiation.

All of the objects and the internal walls have arbitrary $\alpha$'s.

After a long time, take a "shot" of the system.

Is it possible for some values of $\alpha$ for each object and some initial conditions to be arranged in a way that we have, in the long-term stationary, different stable temperatures of different objects?

This will help me get a sense of the exact definition of thermal equilibrium and its relation with stationary temperature state for an object.

An intuitive proof would be better, if any.

Comment: What does Second law say?

Comment: @Deep You can't convert heat fully to work and also you can't make heat flow in the reverse direction, I suppose.

Comment: I mean what does Second law say in regard to attaining equilibrium, in your case thermal equilibrium? Since in your case there is no constraint on heat transfer (such as adiabatic walls) heat transfer will take place until temperature becomes uniform everywhere. $\alpha$ has nothing to do with it.